# Is there any chance for hiding both the content and label in ionic slide?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using [ion-slide-box-tabs](https://github.com/JKnorr91/ion-slide-box-tabs) as reference and tried ion slide box. Now I want to show and hide whole of the ion slide including the ion slide tab label. As for now only the content part is being showed and hidden. Is there any possibilities to hide both the slide and also the label? If so kindly please do help me with this.

Comment: Just style it as normal HTML.

Comment: You should provide HTML code.

Comment: <ion-content scroll="false">
    <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" ion-slide-tabs>
        <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="FirstTab"><h1>Hi</h1></ion-slide>
        <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="SecondTab"><h1>Hello</h1></ion-slide>
        <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="ThirdTab"><h1>How Are You</h1></ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>

Comment: i can hide the content "HI","Hello" and "How Are You". But i couldn't hide the ion-slide-tab-label(i.e,)First,Second and ThirdTab. Is there any chance of hiding both the label and the content of the slide?